# How to view output of OutputDebugString () across the network?

Tags: delphi, debugview, outputdebugstring

Further to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218434/how-to-view-output-of-outputdebugstring), I find that I cannot use the GExpertsDebugWindow on a PC which did not previously have Delphi installed.

If I have the following (not unusal, so probably of interest to others) requirements, do I need to roll my own code or is there and existing and **free** solution?

1. Must be able to read acorss the network (i.e., PC 1 monitors PC 2's debug output) by specifying PC 2's IP address
2. If posible, I would like to be able to filter by process name

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I posted an answer, but then noticed your requirement that it be free, so I deleted it. I've not seen anything free that satisfies your requirements, so can't help there. I posted a comment in response to the comment you just left on your original question a few minutes ago that gives a solution to the `GExpertsDebugWindow` problem. You should really give people a chance to respond before you post a new question. :-)

Comment: +1 Thanks,Ken. I did not excpect anyone to notce my comment to the old post, it was just for posterity's sake.  Hoewever if I can use GExpertsDebugWindow on a PC that never had Delphi installed that woudl certainly help with another problem.  This question still stands though, as I do need to remote access a PC in a rather inaccessable location which has mno montior, mouse or keyboard.

Comment: If your question now is about remote access, it's not really a programming question any longer. :-) You can do that with `VNC` (Google VNC; there are free versions available from several sources); it allows remote access to the machine, even if they're "headless" (no monitor, keyboard, or mouse). But questions about that should go to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) instead of here.

Comment: Have you tried SysInternals' DebugView from Microsoft?

Comment: VNC + DebugView. Done. Voted to close as not programming question.

Comment: Just because it can be solved without any programming doesn't mean it's not a programming question. Debugging techniques are a quintessential programming topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft's [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) tool has those features. It can display `OutputDebugString` output, even from remote systems. Depending on other factors, it can even install itself remotely.

Comment: +1 thanks, Rob. I think I might stick with GExperts and remote desktop into the machine where the program is running ....